# PHP created Excel Sheet creates errors upon opening

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pdo

So, my current code works 100%, the file is made and it is opened in excel. But upon opening, there are a few errors one must click through in order to open the file. They are as follows:

> The file format and extension of 'address-book.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

Then:

> Excel has detected that 'address-book.xls is a SYLK file, but cannot load it. Either the file has errors or it is not a SYLK file format. Click OK to try to open the file in a different format.

Then finally:

> The file format and extension of 'address-book.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

After that it reluctantly opens. Here is the code that creates it.
Any help with formatting the spreadsheet, such as having the cells be big enough for the content would be great. But getting rid of the errors upon opening is my priority.

```
<?PHP
require_once('conn.php');

$colnames = array(
    'id' => "ID",
    'Title' => "Title",
    'First_Name' => "First name",
    'Last_Name' => "Last Name",
    'Address' => "Address",
    'City' => "City",
    'State' => "State",
    'Zipcode' => "Zipcode",
    'Home_Phone' => "Home Phone",
    'Cell_Phone' => "Cell Phone",
    'Email1' => "Email #1",
    'Email2' => "Email #2"
);

function map_colnames($input){
    global $colnames;
    return isset($colnames[$input]) ? $colnames[$input] : $input;
}
function cleanData(&$str){
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

$filename = "address-book";

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
$flag = false;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$sDB_table." ORDER BY Last_Name";
$query = $sDBConn -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();
while(false !== ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
    if(!$flag){
        $firstline = array_map(__NAMESPACE__ . '\map_colnames', array_keys($row));
        echo implode("\t", $firstline) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
exit;
```

?>

PHPExcel Error:

```
$colnames = array("Title","First name","Last Name","Address","City","State","Zipcode","Home Phone","Cell Phone","Email #1","Email #2");
$col = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

// Add Headers
for($i=0;$i<count($colnames);$i++){
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue($col[$i]."1", $colnames[$i]);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$sDB_table." ORDER BY Last_Name";
$query = $sDBConn -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();

$rownum = 1;
//Add Content
while(false !== ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
    $rownum++;
    for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue($col[$i]."".$rownum, $row[$i]);        
    }
}
```

The error occurs when it hits the while statement, if I take that part out, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `ID` as the first two bytes of your file. This is the signature for a SYLK file, an old spreadsheet format used by Multiplan (Symbolic Link Interchange - SYLK - file format), a precursor to Microsoft Excel.

The easiest way to resolve this is to avoid `ID` as your heading, and use `Id` (IIRC, the SYLK signature is case-sensitive) or `Key` or some other text value instead

---

You're saving your file with an `xls` extension, but you're not actually using Excel format, simply a csv format; so MS Excel will complain that the format doesn't match the extension.... either change the extension to `.csv` to match the actual format of the file you're creating; or create a real BIFF-format Excel file

---

`Any help with formatting the spreadsheet, such as having the cells be big enough for the content would be great.`

The format that you're using, csv (with a tab separator) doesn't support formatting of any kind, including column widths. If you want that, then you need to switch to a true spreadsheet format (by coincidence, SYLK is a true spreadsheet format, though it's pretty dated and I wouldn't particularly recommend it) such as BIFF for real xls files, OfficeOpenXML for xlsx files, OASIS for ods files.

---

Headers that I use for OfficeOpenXML xlsx files:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: If you want to give it an extension of `xls`, then Excel will complain if it's anything other than BIFF-format; personally, I prefer `xlsx` using OfficeOpenXML format.... OfficeOpenXML has been the MS Excel default format for the past 9 years

Comment: Alright I'll attempt to implement that, any chance you could show me how my changed headers would look if I were to change it to a xlsx?

Comment: You'll have fun if you want to try and create `xlsb` format, you'll not find any libraries that can help you

Comment: It says that the file extension xlsx is invalid. Is that due to the fact that the file is being downloaded?

Comment: Nothing to do with that..... you can't simply change the headers, you have to change the file format of what you're creating...... a csv file is a csv file regardless of the headers you send: if you want a BIFF-format xls file, then you have to actually create a BIFF-format file to send to the browser, not a csv file; if you want a OffiecOpenXML-format xlsx file, then you have to actually create a OfficeOpenXMLformat file to send to the browser, not a csv file..... simply changing the headers doesn't change the content/structure of the file that you're sending in any way

Comment: Last question, what library do you recommend using for creation of .xlsx files?

Comment: I'd recommend [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/), because I wrote it

Comment: I got it working with PHPExcel, except it breaks when it hits my cell creation made from mysql. Updated main post with more info.

Comment: Breaks with memory problems? Breaks with too many rows? Breaks in what way?

Comment: I found the issue, I was attempting to go through the row generated by the sql by number, but I have to use their collumn names. Like $row['Title'], is there a way to make it so I can just use $row[1]?

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` means "by column name"; `PDO::FETCH_NUM` means "by column number".... [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: You can also simplify this by writing each set of columns in a single call, rather than looping over each column: replace `for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue($col[$i]."".$rownum, $row[$i]);        
    }` with `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row, null, 'A'.$rownum);`

Comment: That's amazing, thank you. I am starting on formatting now, I can't seem to find something to change the width of columns. Is there a function that allows auto-width so the cells are nicely fit?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation).... for setting column width to automatic, [look here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-a-columns-width)